# Enable alias unfolding in command's suggestion

Tags: alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I would like to have alias unfolding in command's suggestions, when invoked in zsh (I'm using oh-my-zsh), to be able to use in full built-in aliasses.

So I.m expecting something like this:

```sh
gca<Tab><Tab>
gca  - git commit -v -a
gca! - git commit -v -a --amend
gcam - git commit -a -m
....
```